# Why is the imaginary unit conventionally put on the right hand side of commutation relations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, conventions

Commutation relations in quantum mechanics are usually written in the form
$$
[x_i,p_j] = i \hbar \delta_{ij}
$$
with the imaginary unit $i$ put on the right hand side of the equation. But  alternatively one could write
$$
\frac{1}{i}[x_i,p_j] = \hbar \delta_{ij}
$$
putting the imaginary unit $i$ on the left hand side.

The advantage of the latter form is that putting the imaginary unit on the left hand side will transform both sides of the relation into real quantities. 
I find this less confusing, because the commutation relations are then relations between real and therefore observable quantities. Also it becomes obvious, that the imaginary unit $i$ is "necessary" to transform the left hand side into a observable quantity, whereas in the traditional form of the commutation relation I was always puzzled about what it means that a commutator is complex. I believe these are good reasons for putting the imaginary unit on the left hand side of commutator relations, but I've never seen this form in the books.

So why is the imaginary unit conventionally put on the right hand side of commutation relations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions [about the reason for notations/conventions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4063/50583).

Comment: I believe this question is more than just about convention. It touches also the question whether a "pure" commutator $[a,b]$ is actually a physical meaningful quantity or not. I believe it is not, because it is a complex quantity and not an observable. But I could be wrong, there might be other important reasons why relations between complex quantities like commutator relations are still of interest in QM and that is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer matters of convention, but here's my take: the traditional way of writing them keeps everything about the operators on the left, and it's more useful to know during calculations. If I know the commutator, then when the commutator turns up I know to just replace with it with $i \hbar$. If I knew your formula, there's an extra mental step of moving the $i$ around. Also, your formula requires either a fraction or a minus sign, both of which make things messier and easier to screw up.

In addition, I think most people who do physics, especially QM, for long enough don't mind complex numbers, and don't necessarily feel that things "ought" to be real.

Answer (score 1):

The $i$ in the formula of commutator is necessary in order to make the quantities hermitian. Indeed, the commutator of two hermitian operators is **NOT** hermitian, but anti-hermitian.
\begin{equation}
\left(\left[x_i , p_j \right] \right)^\dagger = - \left[x_i^\dagger, p_j \dagger\right] = - \left[x_i , p_j \right] \ .
\end{equation}
In a certain sense - it does not very much sense to talk about "real" and "complex" operators, actually - the commutator is not a "real" operator (in the sense it does not have real eigenvalues).